# How do I add snackbar?

Tags: firebase, flutter, snackbar

I dont know why the Snackbar doesnt show up.But when I delete the function off the firebaseauth it shows the snackbar.

Code:

```
MaterialButton(
              onPressed: (){
                try{
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text).then((signedUser) {
                    userCollection.doc(signedUser.user?.uid).set({
                      'username': usernameController.text,
                      'email': emailController.text,
                      'password': passwordController.text,
                      'uid': signedUser.user?.uid,
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen()));
                  });
                } catch(e) {
                  print(e.toString());
                  var snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString()));
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
                }
              },
              elevation: 0,
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 40.h,
              child: Text("Buat akun"),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
            )
```

Comment: You Add the snackbar in exception, that why no showing,

Comment: add another snackbar in try block, it will shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using then so the error won't be caught in the catch section.

You should remove the try catch block and catch the error with catchError() instead like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text).then((signedUser) {
                    userCollection.doc(signedUser.user?.uid).set({
                      'username': usernameController.text,
                      'email': emailController.text,
                      'password': passwordController.text,
                      'uid': signedUser.user?.uid,
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen()));
                  }).catchError((e) {
                    print(e.toString());
                    var snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString()));
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
                  });
```

Comment: How do I give a custom text snackbar from the firebase error text like from ([firebase_auth/weak-password] Password should be at least 6 characters) => (Password should be at least 6 characters).

Comment: In your code before calling createUserWithEmailAndPassword(), you can check for any conditions as follows and return if they aren't validated:

```
onPressed: (){
   if(passwordController.text.length < 6){
var snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text("Password is too short"));
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
return;
}
}
```

Comment: what about if the email already used?

Comment: I think then you should use async/await style for catching specific FirebaseAuthException instead of using .then at the end.

```
try{
await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword();
} on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
}
```

Now exception will be of type FirebaseAuthException and you can access the properties like error codes with e.code and provide a custom message for these codes.

Details of these error codes can be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#error-codes_12

Comment: I already tried it but it only give the error default firebase message. Is there something wrong?

Comment: '''on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                      var errorCode = e.code;
                      var errorMessage = e.message;
                      if (errorCode == "auth/weak-password") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("password too weak"),));
                      } else {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text(errorMessage.toString()),
                        ));
                      }'''